# Which ActionBar Script Do You Recommend?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I've been looking at a few ActionBar scripts that support SDK 1.6 and above. Here's the three main ones I'm looking at:

- https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar
- http://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock
- http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=240

Which one do you recommend?  or if you have another suggestion, let me know.

Comment: Sherlock is based on john nilsson's(first one) and i like it ...  i didn't use greendroid ... known problem(which i resolve in my trunk by messing with resources) you can not have both spinner and menu in Sherlock(but you can have it in orginal Honeycomb) any way Sherloc implementation use own in API < 10 and buildin one on honecomb or higher

Comment: @Matt  Based on design and stability I guess.  I'm just looking for opinions from people who might have used them. :-)

Comment: @Selvin Thanks for your comments.  Good to know about that known issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActionBarSherlock is great library I've used it on several projects from Android 2.1 to 4.0 (it;s compatible to 1.6), the dev Jake Wharton is great at including the latest features from the Android compatibility library very quickly.

Here's a [link](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.actionbarsherlock.sample.demos) to the demo app useful for seeing some of the things you can do with it.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend google ioschedule app pattern. You could download it's source code.

Comment: Thanks.  I did see that one too.  I'll have to download the source and have a look.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the actionbar that is provided in the [backward compatibility api](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html)?

Comment: becouse there is no ActionBar

Comment: Oh, so he wants to emulate the actionbar on pre-3.0 devices?

Comment: that's what that libraries do

Comment: Correct Kurtis.  I like the actionbar so I'm looking to implement it on pre-3.0 devices. :-)

Comment: Hi.  I have a question .. does the 'up' icon will works on compatible SDK v4?  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Home

Comment: @xDragonZ Please ask this in a new question.

Comment: @ShannonCole Ah, I see. Please disregard then.

Comment: @Kurtis Oh,sorry.  I don't want ask it as new question cuz I worry it will receive many down votes from user